# E: Could not configure 'coreutils:i386'

Tags: apt, package-management

Any time I try to do any `apt` operation such as : `apt-get update` or `apt-get autoremove`.

I get this error:

```
E: Could not configure 'coreutils:i386'. 
E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'coreutils:i386'. Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)
E: Could not configure 'coreutils:i386'.
```

Comment: try `sudo dpkg --configure coreutils:i386` or `sudo dpkg --install coreutils:i386`

Comment: dpkg: error processing archive coreutils:i386 (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 coreutils:i386

Comment: Ya gotta get all the letters in there!

Comment: I did, And the same error

Comment: K - the man page suggests trying to specifically install this package - try `sudo apt install coreutils:i386`

Comment: I get a lot of errors and finally :
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution), 

and when I try to 'apt-get -f install , I have the same error above. :(

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run `sudo apt-get install -f` or `sudo dpkg --configure coreutils:i386` to finish any held up installation/configuration tasks.  Once completed, you should be able to update or remove other packages.

Comment: The same error show again